# UITableView crashes when it's scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've already read similar question but still cannot solve. 
I've a `UITableView` that crashes in `cellForRowAt` function when it's scrolled (quickly). The crash does not happen at a specific point in the table, but at random.
This is the error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

This is my `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "menuCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MenuTableCell
    return self.setMenuCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

`setMenuCell` is:

```
private func setMenuCell(cell: MenuTableCell?, indexPath: IndexPath) -> MenuTableCell {
    print(indexPath.row, self.menuManager.menusCount)
    cell?.cliccaPerInfoLabel.text = LocalizedStrings.otherDishes
    cell?.altriPiattiLabel.isHidden = !((self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row).getDishes().count) > 3)
    cell?.piatto3Label.isHidden = !((self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row).getDishes().count) >= 3)
    cell?.numeroMenuLabel.text = "Menu \(indexPath.row+1)"
    cell?.numeroPiattiLabel.text = String(format: LocalizedStrings.numberOfDishes, (self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row).getDishes().count))
    cell?.piatto1Label.text = String(format: LocalizedStrings.dishNumber, 1, (self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row).getDishes()[0].getDescription()))
    cell?.piatto2Label.text = String(format: LocalizedStrings.dishNumber, 2, (self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row).getDishes()[1].getDescription()))
    return cell!
    }
```

`self.menuManager` is an object that keeps trace of menu.
Can't understand what's wrong.
Thanks in advance for help!

**Update**

This is my `numberOfRowsInSection` function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.menuManager.menusCount
}
```

Comment: Which line crashes?

Comment: Show your `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't always crashes on the same line.

Comment: You are force unwrapping your cell in the 'setMenuCell' method which I'm sure is what is causing this. I don't see a reason as to why you are leaving cellForRowAt to do tings as simple as adjust labels. Move all that junk into cellForRowAt and see if it still crashes.

Comment: Index out of range usually occurs when accessing arrays, you have a few lines of code that access specific indexes of the arrays, are you sure these arrays exist correctly when accessing them?

You should look at the stack trace when the app crashes, this will probably help you find where this error gets thrown.

How are you populating the data? from a webservice? are you sure you have the correct data ALWAYS being sent to the table view?

Comment: So many unneseccary code... if you shorten it, you get an answer quicker

Comment: It seems that `self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row)` is crashing, or `self.menuManager.getMenu(index: indexPath.row).getDishes()[1]` is causing the crash. Could you give us the whole error? If it's alway index 1 or 0 that's seems to be the second, if it's the first, one, you just need to debug (you could add prints before/after the access, and check the culprit). But clearly, you do a lot of same lines (like the one I copied), factorize it, it will be simpler.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/J8YhnzkX You need to debug.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic readers-writers problem. I think you should make the object that is being accessed by `menuManager.menusCount`, `menuManager.getMenu`, etc. be thread-safe.